# Python connect mySQL database write to text file

Tags: python, mysql

I connect my python to MySQL server with mySQL-Connector(in pyCharm)  and i can read from server then write text file.This seems to be:

```
(1, 'PENELOPE', 'GUINESS', datetime.datetime(2006, 2, 15, 4, 34, 33))
(2, 'NICK', 'WAHLBERG', datetime.datetime(2006, 2, 15, 4, 34, 33))
(3, 'ED', 'CHASE', datetime.datetime(2006, 2, 15, 4, 34, 33))
(4, 'JENNIFER', 'DAVIS', datetime.datetime(2006, 2, 15, 4, 34, 33))
(5, 'JOHNNY', 'LOLLOBRIGIDA', datetime.datetime(2006, 2, 15, 4, 34, 33))
```

I need to  change the commas which are between two areas from **,** to ~ i can find source code could you help me ?Which class I do change?
this is my python code

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="2153417",
  database="sakila"
)
tweets = open("keywords.txt", "w")
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM actor")

with open("C:/Users/Erhan/PycharmProjects/MySQL/keywords.txt", "w", newline='') as f:
    for row in mycursor:
        print(row, file=f)
```

this is working correctly just need change commas(**,**) among name,surname and datetime

like this

```
(1~ 'PENELOPE' ~ 'GUINESS' ~ datetime.datetime(2006, 2, 15, 4, 34, 33)) 
 (2~ 'NICK' ~ 'WAHLBERG' ~ datetime.datetime(2006, 2, 15, 4, 34, 33))
```

Comment: Please don't try and use `<br/>` for line breaks. It doesn't work. Copy/paste code blocks, highlight all of it in one go and use ctrl + k, or click the `{}` button in the editor

Comment: Change `print(row, file=f)` to `f.write(' '.join(row))`

Comment: sorry this is my first question 
 i need this
I need this like: (1, 'PENELOPE' ~ 'GUINESS' ~ datetime.datetime(2006, 2, 15, 4, 34, 33)) 
(2, 'NICK' ~ 'WAHLBERG' ~ datetime.datetime(2006, 2, 15, 4, 34, 33))

Answer (score 0):

<s>Assuming you want the string representation of all objects(e.g `2006-02-15 04:34:33`) instead of the objects representations `datetime.datetime(2006, 2, 15, 4, 34, 33)`, try this:</s>

As per your requirement, try this:

```py
print(' ~ '.join(map(repr, row)), file=f)
```

I would recommend to try directly writing to the file instead:

```py
f.write(' ~ '.join(map(repr, row))
```

Comment: I need this like: 
(1~ 'PENELOPE' ~ 'GUINESS' ~ datetime.datetime(2006, 2, 15, 4, 34, 33))
 (2~ 'NICK' ~ 'WAHLBERG' ~ datetime.datetime(2006, 2, 15, 4, 34, 33))

Comment: Updated answer @erhanxx

Comment: Mark it as the answer if it helped you.